# Make a Server wait for input from two different controllers

Tags: java, sockets, javafx, server

I made a client-server application where the server has to send a list of emails to the client, which after load that into a ListView gives the possibility, through a menuBar, to delete them. In the client all these operations are made in the Data Model (I followed the MVC pattern). This is the server:

```
class ThreadedEchoHandler implements Runnable {

    private Socket incoming;

    private String nomeAccount = "";

    public void run() {
        try {
            incoming = s.accept();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("Unable to accept requests");
        }
        contenutoTextArea.append("Connected from: " + incoming.getLocalAddress() + "\n");
        textarea.setText(contenutoTextArea.toString());
        try {
            //PHASE 1: The server receives the email
            try {
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(incoming.getInputStream()));
                nomeAccount = in.readLine();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                System.out.println("Not works");
            }

            //PHASE 2: I'm getting all the emails from the files
            File dir = new File("src/server/" + nomeAccount);
            String[] tmp = new String[100];
            int i = 0;
            for (File file : dir.listFiles()) {
                if (file.isFile() && !(file.getName().equals(".DS_Store"))) {
                    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))) {
                        String line;
                        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                            tmp[i++] = line;
                        }
                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                        System.out.println("Cannot read from file");
                    }
                }
            }

            //PHASE 3: The server sends the ArrayList to the client
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(incoming.getOutputStream(), true);
            for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
                out.println(tmp[j]); // send the strings to the client
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("Cannot send the strings to the client");
        }

        //PHASE 4: Here I loop and wait for the client choise
        BufferedReader in;
        String op;
        try {
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(incoming.getInputStream()));
            while ((op = in.readLine()) != null) {                   
                if (op.equals("Elimina")) {
                    String tmp = in.readLine();
                    File file = new File("src/server/" + nomeAccount + "/" + tmp + ".txt");
                    file.delete();
                } else if (op.equals("Invia")) {
                    //...
                } else {
                    //...
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("Non so");

        } finally {
            try {
                incoming.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                System.out.println("Cannot closing the socket");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

These are the methods of the client:

```
public void loadData() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException, ParseException {

    try {
        s = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 5000);
        ArrayList<Email> email = new ArrayList<Email>();
        DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        Date data;

        /* PHASE 1: The client sends a string to the server */
        //try {
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream(), true);
            out.println(account); // send the account name to server

            /* PHASE 2: The client receives the ArrayList with the emails */
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
            String line;
            String message[] = new String[5];
            for (int j=0; (line = in.readLine()) != null;) {
                message[j++] = line;
                if (j==5) {
                    data = format.parse(message[3]);
                    email.add(new Email((Integer.parseInt(message[0])), message[1], account, message[2], message[4], data));
                    j=0;
                }
            }

            //Casting the arrayList
            emailList = FXCollections.observableArrayList(email);

            //Sorting the emails
            Collections.sort(emailList, (Email o1, Email o2) -> {
                if (o1.getData() == null || o2.getData() == null) {
                    return 0;
                }
                return o1.getData().compareTo(o2.getData());
            });

        /*} finally {
            s.close();*/
        //}
    } catch (SocketException se) {
        emailList.setAll(null, null);
    }
}

public void deleteMail(Email da_elim) throws IOException {
    int id_del = da_elim.getID();
    emailList.remove(da_elim);
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream(), true);
    out.println("Elimina");
    out.println(id_del);
}
```

The PHASE 1, 2, 3 of the Server are for the upload of the emails, and work with the loadData() method. Without the PHASE 4 the program works. Now, if I write that loop, the GUI of the client doesn't load and I cannot press on the DELETE button (which should make the input to innescate something (in this the elimination of the file) into that loop. Why the client doesn't load even if they are two different threads? And why without that loop it works?

EDIT: with the Listener class implemented but still doesn't works

```
//PHASE 4: Here I loop and wait for the client choise      
        BufferedReader in;
        String op;
        try {
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(incoming.getInputStream()));
            /*while ((op = in.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println("OP: " + op);
                if (op.equals("Elimina")) {
                    String tmp = in.readLine();
                    contenutoTextArea.append("Ho eliminato la mail ").append(tmp).append(" \n");
                    textarea.setText(contenutoTextArea.toString());
                    File file = new File("src/server/" + nomeAccount + "/" + tmp + ".txt");
                    file.delete();
                }
            }*/
            Listener lis = new Listener(in, new LinkedBlockingQueue<String>());
            lis.run();
            System.out.println("bbbbb");
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("Unable to read messages");
        } finally {
            try {
                incoming.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                System.out.println("Cannot close the socket");
            }
        }
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: whatever your code does, it _must_ access nodes (and all of their properties) on the fx application thread (your snippet violates that rule)

Comment: What you mean for nodes? Because the client has a DataModel which store and get all the data and the only function of the Server is to send it the information stored into a bunch of .txt files

Comment: _textArea.setText_ sounds like setting the text on ... a TextArea ;)

Comment: @kleopatra I don't understand what is the problem. I can access to all the fx elements from my controller because they are declared as global variable, so they can be used wherever I want (in my threads etc..)

Comment: sure, I believe that you can do it, technically. But you __MUST NOT__ access nodes in the scenegraph off the fx application thread (please read comments carefully .. typically they contain usefule information, that's why I write them ;) If you don't understand, read up on the terms you don't know - here the fx application thread which I mentioned twice. Now do it before wasting more of all our time, including your own!

Answer (score 2):

I think you should run jvisualvm (it's a tool installed with jdk in /bin/ location of your jdk) and look for that Thread lifecycle you create on server. Also check if your Thread don't go through the code and just ends his life skipping waiting for client.

Is this Thread somehow connected with client? Because you cannot run client App. Are they separated? Another think that came to my mind is using

```
Platform.runLater(()->{
});
```

if your client GUI is in JavaFX. Use it if you are creating GUI, changing values in fields and anything you do on your GUI. Maybe your server is waiting for user response and after that GUI is built? Which causes that you can't press DELETE button.

Comment: The client is in a different package. The server lifecycle doesn't end because it get stuck in the `while ((op = in.readLine()) != null) line`. When I try to execute the client nothing appear, but if I close the server then it seems to get "unlocked" and the GUI loads.

Comment: I've also tried with Platform.runLater but nothing changed

Answer (score 2):

I'm not currently able to comment, so I can't ask for clarification, but I think I'm correctly interpreting what's wrong. "The program hangs when it enters a loop that waits for input from two controllers". Assuming I got that part right, the most likely culprit would be that buffered reader is hanging indefinitely because its not receiving input. When I first ran into this issue, I threw it inside its own "receiver" class and used a Queue to bus over anything it received to a loop in my main class. my code looked something like this:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue;

public class Listener implements Runnable
{
    private BufferedReader br;
    private BlockingQueue<String> q;
    private boolean shouldClose = false;

    public Listener(BufferedReader br, BlockingQueue<String> q)
    {
        this.q = q;
        this.br = br;
    }

    public void run()
    {
        loop();
        System.out.println("listener has stopped");
    }

    public void loop()
    {
        String line = "";

        try
        {
            while((line = br.readLine()) != null && !shouldClose)
            {
                q.put(line);
            }
        }
        catch (IOException | InterruptedException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void shutdown()
    {
        shouldClose = true;
    }
}
```

apologies if I've misunderstood in any way, or missed something in your code.

Comment: I updated the question with that part of the code adapted to this class, but the client still doesn't load the GUI unless I doesn't close the client. I wrote a println right before the while in the Listener class and it works, but I put it inside the while or outside it doesn't works, so I think it still get stuck on that condition.

Comment: is your listener object it's own thread? if It is, you should call lis.start(); if its not, then there isn't much of an advantage to what I suggested. probably my bad though. I never explicitly stated that it this needs multi-threading. then you can just make phase 4 a loop that checks to see if the queue has stuff, and then acts accordingly.

Comment: The Listener object is in a controller thread, but it doesn't start a new one. Doesn't a new loop would block the program just like the readLine function does?

Comment: you are correct, having the readline function will result in a hanging program pretty much always. the point of putting it in a loop in its very own thread is that it can hang as much as it wants without stopping the rest of the program. does that clear things up?